# Partial random selection of items from numpy array from items that meet certain condition

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, random

I have a `bool` array that was created with respect to a `double` array:

```
array1 = ... # the double array initialization
array2 = array1 < threshold # threshold is set somewhere else
```

Assuming the output of my second array is like this:

```
# array2 = [True, False, True, True, True, False]
```

I want to select percentage of the `True` items. For example, if I want to randomly select `75%` of the True items, the output would be any of these:

```
# array3 = [True, False, True, True, False, False]
# array3 = [False, False, True, True, True, False]
# array3 = [True, False, False, True, True, False]
```

The third array contains 3 out of the 4 True items that were found in the second array. How can I achieve this?

Comment: To use the linked one, do : `make_more_sparsey(a,int(np.round(len(idx)*(1-0.75))))`. i.e. use `idx` from the function implementation.

Comment: @Divakar Where exactly did you get the idea that I asked to replace `random` elements in general? I want to choose random set from the `True` elements. The "linked question" clearly DOES NOT have the answer I need.

Comment: It's not picking random elems, its picking from the True elements. Read the Q&A again please.

Comment: @Divakar I see now, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, that is actually just a job of

1. getting all the indexes of `True` in your vector -> `true_indices`
2. shuffle `true_indices`
3. `true_indices = true_indices[0:len(true_indices)*3/4`
4. `array3 = [False]*len(array2)`
5. `array3[true_indices] = True`

done. all these "I need to randomly pick a fixed amount from a set" is usually well convertible to a shuffling method.

Numpy comes with a `shuffle` function.

Comment: Thank you a lot. This is very smart. Anyway, I have a four-dimensional array in my application and when I get the indices I get a `tuple` of four arrays. I am unable to resize the arrays in the tuple.. :(

Comment: you don't have to resize – just shuffle the index vector and pick as many as you need from that.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion